# Como guardar caracteres en C

Tags: c

Lo que intento hacer es que "dato"='S' y cuando vuelva a correr por do while no remplaze 'S' si no agregue otra 'S' y me retorne "dato"='S','S'. Ojla y me explique.

```
void * menu(char * nombre){
char pokemon[]="\n Charmander[C]   Bulbasaur[B]\n Squirtle[S]   Pikachu[P]\n";
char opcion_poke;
char * entrenador;
int terminado = 0;
do { 
    printf("%s ",pokemon);
    scanf("%c%*c",&opcion_poke);
    opcion_poke = toupper(opcion_poke);
    switch (opcion_poke) {
        case 'C':
            printf("\n Elejiste a Charmander\n Ten paciencia con el %s\n",nombre);
            entrenador = "C";
            terminado++;
            if(terminado==2){
                entrenador = "CC";
            }else if(terminado==3){
                entrenador = "CCC";
            }else{
                printf("Error");
            }
            terminado++;
            break;
        case 'B':
            printf("\n Elejiste a Bulbasaur\n Resulta facil criarlo %s\n",nombre);
            entrenador = "B";
            terminado++;
            break;
        case 'S':
            printf("\n Elejiste a Squirtle\n Merece la pena %s Si Si!!\n",nombre);
            entrenador = "S";
            terminado++;
            break;
        case 'P':
            printf("\n Elijiste a Pikachu\n Es un pokemon muy electrisante %s\n",nombre);
            entrenador = "P";
            terminado++;
            break;
        default:
            printf("\n Elija una Opcion valida\n");
            break;
    }
}while (terminado!=3);
return (entrenador);
```

}

con ese if me retorna 'CCC'  pero si marca otra opcion y luego esta tendria que ser algo haci el retorno 'CBS' claro depende de la opcion que marque. Alguien ayude

Comment: ¿Quieres una lista con las opciones que el usuario eligió?

Comment: si pero que esa lista este en cadena para retornarlo

Comment: ose que esa lista este en la variable entrenador

Comment: ¿Y el limite es tres opciones?

Answer (score 1):

Esto se logra usando **reserva dinámica de memoria**.
Tu variable `entrenador` cambia por esto:

```c
char *entrenador = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);
```

`malloc` es una función parte de la librería `stdlib`,
***intenta reservar*** una porción contigua de memoria, `free`
(tambien de `stdlib`) libera la memoria reservada
por `malloc`.

`sizeof` es un operador de `C` y devuelve el **número de

bytes** que usa cada tipo de dato, variable o estructura.

```c
sizeof(char)  -> 1

/* Estos valores pueden ser diferentes
 * dependiendo de la arquitectura y compilador. */
sizeof(short) -> 2
sizeof(int)   -> 4
sizeof(long)  -> 8
```

`malloc` recibe como parámetro la **cantidad de bytes**
a obtener, si tiene éxito devuelve un puntero de tipo
**void *** al inicio del bloque de memoria reservada o
**NULL** en caso contrario. Reservar memoria con `malloc`
es parecido a crear un *arreglo*:

```
char *ptr = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 5) -> 0x0023

 0  1  2  3  4
[?][?][?][?][?]
 ^  ^  ^  ^  ^
 |  |  |  |  +--> 0x0027
 |  |  |  +-----> 0x0026
 |  |  +--------> 0x0025
 |  +-----------> 0x0024
 +--------------> 0x0023
```

Y se puede acceder de la misma forma:

```c
ptr[0] = 'h';
ptr[1] = 'o';
ptr[2] = 'l';
ptr[3] = 'a';

/* Pero para crear una cadena de caracteres valida
 * tenemos que agregar manualmente un carácter nulo. */
ptr[4] = '\0';
```

Para guardar las opciones que el usuario eligió
solo tienes que recorrer el bloque de memoria que
acabas de crear:

1. Comienzas en la posición cero.
2. El usuario elige una opción.
3. Guardas la opción que el usuario acaba de elegir.
4. Te mueves a la siguiente posición.
5. Repites desde el paso dos hasta llenar tu lista.

Este es tu código usando `malloc`:

```c
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TAM_LISTA 3

char *menu(const char *nombre) {
    char pokemon[] = "\n Charmander[C]   Bulbasaur[B]\n Squirtle[S]   Pikachu[P]\n";
    char opcion_poke;
    char *entrenador = NULL;
    int terminado = 0;
    
    // Necesitamos un espacio extra para el carácter nulo.
    if ((entrenador = (char *)malloc((sizeof(char) * TAM_LISTA) + 1)) == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    
    do {
        printf("%s ",pokemon);
        scanf("%c%*c",&opcion_poke);
        opcion_poke = toupper(opcion_poke);
        
        switch (opcion_poke) {
            case 'C':
                printf("\n Elegiste a Charmander.\n Ten paciencia con el %s.\n", nombre);
                entrenador[terminado++] = opcion_poke;
            break;
            
            case 'B':
                printf("\n Elegiste a Bulbasaur.\n Resulta fácil criarlo %s.\n", nombre);
                entrenador[terminado++] = opcion_poke;
            break;
            
            case 'S':
                printf("\n Elegiste a Squirtle.\n Merece la pena %s ¡¡Sí sí!!\n", nombre);
                entrenador[terminado++] = opcion_poke;
            break;
            
            case 'P':
                printf("\n Elegiste a Pikachu.\n Es un pokemon muy electrizante %s.\n", nombre);
                entrenador[terminado++] = opcion_poke;
            break;
            
            default:
                printf("\n Elija una opción valida.\n");
            break;
        }
    } while (terminado < TAM_LISTA);
    
    entrenador[terminado] = '\0';
    
    return (entrenador);
}

int main(){
    char *entrenador = NULL;
    
    if ((entrenador = menu("Ariadna")) != NULL) {
        printf("\n %s\n", entrenador);
        
        // Cuando termines de usar la memoria no olvides liberarla.
        free(entrenador);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

El uso de `malloc` parece complicado al principio
pero como todo solo necesitas practicar para dominarlo.